# FATAL ERROR: Zone Allocation failed - process out of memory + eirslett-frontend-maven-plugin + Java + webpack + Maven

Tags: java, maven, webpack, frontend-maven-plugin

Getting following error while building package.
it can be solve in script while packaging local with **--max_old_space_size=4098** this option.

I tried with `<environmentVariables>` but didn't work as well arguments.

Anyone know the way to set in **frontend-maven-plugin** this plugin.??

**Error Stack**

```
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:webpack (webpack build) @ qtm4jserver ---
[INFO] Running 'webpack.js ' in D:\workspace-server\***\src\main\frontend
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR: Zone Allocation failed - process out of memory
[ERROR]  1: 00007FF61F96AA8F
[ERROR]  2: 00007FF61F912746
[ERROR]  3: 00007FF61F913406
[ERROR]  4: 00007FF6200FA3DE
[ERROR]  5: 00007FF6200E272A
[ERROR]  6: 00007FF61FC0A7AD
[ERROR]  7: 00007FF620311923
[ERROR]  8: 00007FF620310807
[ERROR]  9: 00007FF62047F116
[ERROR] 10: 00007FF62045D0C6
[ERROR] 11: 00007FF62035586A
[ERROR] 12: 00007FF6203724F9
[ERROR] 13: 00007FF620372AC4
[ERROR] 14: 00007FF620372856
[ERROR] 15: 00007FF6203569FE
[ERROR] 16: 00007FF620353F91
[ERROR] 17: 00007FF62035043B
[ERROR] 18: 00007FF62002F347
[ERROR] 19: 00007FF62002ECA1
[ERROR] 20: 00007FF62002EE59
[ERROR] 21: 00007FF61FD606E5
[ERROR] 22: 00007FF62051982D
[ERROR] 23: 00007FF62048E130
[ERROR] 24: 00007FF6205893DD
[ERROR] 25: 00007FF62048DCDC
[ERROR] 26: 00007FF62048DCDC
[ERROR] 27: 00007FF62048DCDC
[ERROR] 28: 00007FF62048DCDC
[ERROR] 29: 00007FF62048706C
[ERROR] 30: 00007FF62048DCDC
[ERROR] 31: 00007FF62048706C
[ERROR] 32: 00007FF62048DCDC
[ERROR] 33: 00007FF62048DCDC
[ERROR] 34: 00007FF62048706C
[ERROR] 35: 00007FF62048DCDC
[ERROR] 36: 00007FF62048DCDC
[ERROR] 37: 00007FF62048706C
[ERROR] 38: 00007FF62048DCDC
[ERROR] 39: 00007FF62048DCDC
[ERROR] 40: 00007FF62048706C
[ERROR] 41: 00007FF62048DCDC
[ERROR] 42: 00007FF62048DCDC
[ERROR] 43: 000000E1CCE4E235
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:40 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-03-25T13:25:41+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:webpack (webpack build) on project qtm4jserver: Failed to run task: 'webpack.js ' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 134 (Exit value: 134) -> [Help 1]
```

**Current Configuration**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
        <workingDirectory>src/main/frontend</workingDirectory>

        <!-- <environmentVariables>


            <!-- Var value take from maven properties -->
            <NODE_OPTIONS>--max_old_space_size=4098</NODE_OPTIONS>
        <NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX>--max_old_space_size=4098</NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX>
        <NODE_ENV>--max_old_space_size=4098</NODE_ENV>

        </environmentVariables>         -->
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install node and npm</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <nodeVersion>v12.7.0</nodeVersion>
                <npmVersion>6.11.3</npmVersion>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>npm install</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>install</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>webpack build</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>webpack</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```